# chrome extension: saving data attribute in background from popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

background.js

```
function getFrame() {
  // popup.js can access background's frame with this function
  return $('iframe')[0];
}

function updateStatus(status) {
  // popup.js should call this function to update the frame's status
  var frame = $('iframe')[0];
  $(frame).data('status', status);
}
```

popup.js

```
..DOM READY
var bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
('.hello').click(function () {
  bg.updateStatus('ready')
}
// <ASSUME THE ABOVE EVENT HAS BEEN TRIGGERED HERE>
var frame = bg.getFrame();
console.log($(frame).data('status')) // undefined <- HOWEVER, THIS IS THE RESULT
```

I am trying to store the status in the background's frame to retrieve it when popup re-opens. However, the above is the result. Could someone explain why this is happening? Am I missing something about `data` attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. Instead of retrieving the `frame` element from `popup`, I had to do the following:

**background.js**

```
function getStatus() {
  // popup.js MUST retrieve the current status this way
  // $(bg.getFrame()).data('status') IS BAD
  var frame = $('iframe')[0];
  return $(frame).data('status');
}
```

Could someone add why exactly this is happening?

Comment: Element's data, as far as I understand, is not part of the DOM, but is maintained by jQuery in the page's context. You can access the background page and its DOM, but popup's copy of jQuery has its own execution context.